# Railway build error "Docker build failed"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, deployment

I am trying to deploy this Express project, but it is not progressing beyond the build, and it seems strange to me. I don't have this issue locally. Any ideas? I have already tried 'CI=false' but that seems to be for React in some cases. I have spent several hours trying to deploy, but I haven't succeeded.

Here I will leave the build log.

```
Dockerfile:24
-------------------
22 |     # build phase
23 |     COPY . /app/.
24 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/9fae86cc-8dcb-4283-ab13-5ad288f3dace-node_modules/cache,target=/app/node_modules/.cache npm run build
25 |
26 |
-------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
 
Error: Docker build failed
```

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "lockfileVersion": 3,
    "requires": true,
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npx tsc",
        "start": "node ./build/server.js",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q build/server.js\""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "joi": "^17.11.0",
        "jose": "^5.1.1",
        "mariadb": "^3.2.2",
        "mysql2": "^3.6.3",
        "sequelize": "^6.35.0",
        "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.5",
        "uuid": "^9.0.1",
        "winston": "^3.11.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.16",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
        "@types/node": "^20.9.0",
        "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
        "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
        "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    }
}
```

I've tried many things, including modifying the package.json without success and even adding new parameters to the .env file (although I doubt this is the issue, as the problem occurs during the application build and not when running it)